# XCode: Single ViewController going to multiple ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have seen a bunch of topics where multiple ViewControllers go to one single ViewController, but not the opposite.

I am making a game where you select a game from Game_select.m and it needs to go out to one of 6 View Controllers. I've tried using storyboard and hardcoding it but neither have worked for me.

I have already imported Game1.h and Game2.h into Game_select.m.
When I run my code it always goes to Game1 ViewController.
This is code I am trying:

```
    if(getGame1) {
    //go to game1
    Game1 *game1 = [[Game1 alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:game1 animated:YES];
    }

    if(getGame2) {
    //go to game2
    Game2 *game2 = [[Game2 alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:game2 animated:YES];
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advanced.
Cheers.

Comment: You are using Game1 to instance game2. Is this a typo in your question? Or it's an error in your code.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry, fixed.

Comment: That looks right, as far as pushing the view controller onto stack. Have you checked that `getGame1` is a nil value?

Comment: @Anthony if by that you mean, am I sure that Game1 is false when Game2 is true, then yes.

Comment: So what you're saying is that no matter what you do, the `Game1` view gets displayed? If you've stepped through the code and are sure that `Game2 *game2 = [[Game2 alloc] init]...` is executed, I'm not sure what to say. Maybe `Game2` is defined improperly somewhere as `Game1`?

Comment: Is there anyway to do it via storyboard or does it have to be hard-coded?

Comment: Is you storyboard imbedded in a `NavigationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create manual segues from your main viewController to the other viewControllers.  First, click on the viewController that you *want to be displayed*.  Make sure you have the viewController itself selected, not one of the views:

[image]

Then click on the segues tab (on the far right) and drag from the "Manual Segue" circle to the viewController you *want to segue from*.

[image]

Then click on the segues and give them different names in the tab like this:

[image]

Then, in your code, you will have a line like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:nil];
```

You would use that to show the viewController for the "showAlternate" identifier.  You will have multiple segues with identifiers like "Game1" and Game2".

Comment: Creating a segue is when you right-click an object and have it go to another ViewController correct? If so, you want me to make some going from the screen where you select which game you want to play to the ViewController of that game? If so, it's only letting me make one segue per button. I do see the identifier field, but whenever I have another segue go from the same button it erases the first one.

Comment: There is a way to create a segue without a button.  I'll update my answer when I get back to my computer today.

Comment: I believe I followed this correctly and I was getting

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Mini_gameselect: 0x1dd4b360>) has no segue with identifier 'game4_segue''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x326222a3 0x3a34a97f 0x34635e31 0x52563 0x345150c5 0x34515077 0x34515055 0x3451490b 0x34514e01 0x3443d5f1 0x3442a801 0x3442a11b 0x361425a3 0x361421d3 0x325f7173 0x325f7117 0x325f5f99 0x32568ebd 0x32568d49 0x361412eb 0x3447e301 0x4d3e3 0x3a781b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Doesn't this create a segue going from Game[n] back to the game_select screen?

Comment: To go back you are going to use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in "game4viewController"

Comment: In your code, when you are ready to return from Game[n] to the game_select screen, you will use that line.  For me, I generally have an `-(IBAction) back;` method that is hooked up to the back button in interface builder.  You would put that line in the implementation of the back method.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't use navigation controllers for this case.  Make all of your viewControllers subclasses of (the normal) `UIViewController`, then use this code to present one of your viewControllers:

Note that this code will only work if you are setting up your view programatically or if using xib's (not storyboard) then this will also work if you use `initWithNibName: bundle:` instead of using `init`

```
if(getGame1) {
    //go to game1
    Game1 *game1 = [[Game1 alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:game1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

if(getGame2) {
    //go to game2
    Game2 *game2 = [[Game2 alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:game2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Also, let me point out that you will have a problem if both getGame1 and getGame2 are true.

Comment: When I try this, the screen just goes black.

Comment: Are you using xibs or are you arranging your views programmatically?

Comment: In that case you will need to use segues.  The reason why this code is not working (and probably your original code too) is because you are not telling Game1 or Game2 that it is supposed to use a storyboard file.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Take a look at my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that `getGame1` and `getGame2` are `BOOL` values and not some sort of object that will evaluate to YES if its non-nil. I have made this mistake many times:

```
NSNumber* booleanValue = @NO;
if (booleanValue) {
    // this code will run
}

if ([booleanValue boolValue]) {
    // this code will not run - as expected
}
```

Seriously, I've made this mistake tons of times.

Comment: I don't think I've run into this problem, but just in case I do thanks, I appreciate it.